# Wait for async data before rendering a list on AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie on Angular JS but have good experience working with Javascript.

In my App I am creating a simple Factory fulfilled by JSON data coming from a web service:

```
.factory('Tools', function($http) { 
    var tools = {content:null};
    var promise = $http.get('/Tool/GetTools').success(function(data) {
        tools.content = data;
        //At this points all the data is on tools.content
    });    
    return {
        promise:promise,
        all: function(){
            return tools;
            //At this point tools equals to null
        }
    }
});
```

But when I want to render the list:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="tool in tools">
        Hello, {{tool}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

The info isn't still there yet.

I have this on my controller:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, Tools) {
  $scope.tools = Tools.all();
});
```

Is there a way to tell the list to "wait" while the Tools object loads from the ajax call before the list renders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return from your factory the promise and into controller you can check the success.
Something like this:
(i've simulated the wait with a timeout)

```js
angular.module('App', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, resultsFactory) {
  
  $scope.results = [{txt: 'Loading..'}];
  resultsFactory.all().then(
    function(res){
      $scope.results = res;
    },
    function(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
})

.factory('resultsFactory', function($http, $timeout, $q) { 
  var results = {};  
  
  function _all(){
    var d = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function(){
            d.resolve([{txt:'one'},{txt:'two'},{txt:'three'}]);
     }, 2000); 
  
    return d.promise;       
  }
  
  results.all = _all;
  return results;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='App'>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <p ng-repeat='res in results'> {{res.txt}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working for me, but I'm using Angular version 1.3.20, any clue regarding the same question with this particular version? Please don't waste time asking why I'm using that version, there are project management reasons for this and a version change is not possible right now.

Comment: @ Amy Pellegrini:  i've updated the snippet's angular version and it works, as previously. maybe your error is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You have to say {{tool}}

Its typo :-)

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="tool in tools">
        Hello, {{tool}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that. Anyway, I am expecting 23 results so if it was the problem, it would print Hello 23 times, right? It is only printing 1 item.

Comment: Dont worry it is already waiting for it Create a controller say myCtrl in this create a varilable $scope.tools=Tools.all(); currently tools have nothing to fill into it but when Tools.all() returns some data it will automatically bind it with view that is called two way binding you don't need to worry about it.
sorry for bad english.

Comment: Thanks. I have that on my controller (I've just added that snipet to my question). Still no luck. I have access to "tools" on my view, but it is empty by the time the list is rendered, and it doesn't seem to be a binding between my list and my tools variable.

Comment: Change in your factory :-
.factory('Tools', function($http) { 
    var tools = null;
    var promise = $http.get('/Tool/GetTools').success(function(data) {
        tools = data;
        //At this points all the data is on tools.content
    });    
    return {
        promise:promise,
        all: function(){
            return tools;
            //At this point tools equals to null
        }
    }
});